# acpi problems make wakeup every midnight

Tags: acpi, wakeup

Since i installed Ubuntu on my Medion Akoya E7214, i have funny problems. It took some time to realize this. With standard settings, my computer woke up every midnight. That annoyed a lot. So i searched and found, that `acpi` is the problem.

- I tried to boot with option `acpi=off` (in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in the kernel-statement of the menu). But now the shutdown isn't working well. I have to switch power off manually and it seems to shut down much more slowly.
- Now, i tried `acpi=noirq` and i had no keyboard anymore. Fortunately, i had an external keyboard to make changes back.

I changed it to `acpi=off` again. But this isn't what i really want.

Can anyone give me a clue how to deactivate this wakeup on midnight without deactivating whole `acpi`? This seems to be a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabing ACPI should be a last resort, in case you've almost given up. Check your BIOS settings whether you have a scheduled wakeup, it's called *Resume by Alarm* on AWARD BIOSes.

Comment: I wandered about that, but there is no BIOS setting about that. I have an American Megatrends BIOS and there is nothing about Alarm or ACPI or wakeup to set in it.

Comment: It could be a combination of BIOS settings and a cron. Check your `/var/log/syslog` file for events after midnight.

Comment: I found it! It was a simple BIOS-bug. With a BIOS-update the problem is solved. No nightly wakeup (for my computer and also for me) but good sleep. Thank you for your help.